# Mounting a networked folder on Linux System for Storing Files?

Tags: java, linux, unix, file-upload, file-sharing

I have two RHEL linux server and the problem that I have is that I am not aware of how to use the other one as a file storage server. Consider there are two servers A & B, now I want server A to have a folder that is mapped to the Server B and then whenever I store something on server A it automatically is moved to server B. I think this is called Networked Drive or May be Mounting a networked folder or File Server. I am totally unaware of this. Please help me to figure this out. Since the server B has a huge storage capacity and I want to save all the files in this through a Java EE program running on Server A.

Please let me know any tools or technology that can help in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `nfs` to mount remote filesystem on a server.

On server B, you may set `/etc/exports` as follows:

```
# See exports(5) for a description.
# This file contains a list of all directories exported to other computers.
# It is used by rpc.nfsd and rpc.mountd.

/folder/to/export SERVER_A_IP(rw)
```

Then, start `nfs` service and, from server A you may use:

`mount -t nfs SERVER_B_IP:/folder/to/export /mnt/mountpoint`

However, your question should have been posted on ServerFault. I flagged it as off topic, hope they move it.

Comment: Thanks for Flagging it. I still have another question this  `/mnt/mountpoint` is a usual thing or a directory?

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh, it's and arbitrary folder on your filesystem. From that point, everytime you access `/mnt/mountpoint` (but it could be also `/home/user/whatsoever` if you prefer, `/mnt` it's just a convention) on server A, it will show the content of `/folder/to/export/` on server B, and every change will affect server B since that's a remote filesystem mounted locally. Is that clear?

Comment: I am able to do the thing mentioned above. The only problem I face is that whatever I put in Master is replicate on client. But Client has no permissions to do anything... no read write access :( Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: @ShivKumarGanesh, do you nave permission to write in the folder where you're mounting it?

Comment: Sorry for delaying the correct point. The solution is great. I just used no_squash_root for this during configuration.